# How to send email in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net site which somewhere requires new users to do registration. In the registration form, their name, password & email-id are asked. Now if the user forgets his password, I want to mail him his password on the email-id he has given.

Now how to mail him ??

Any link or any tips would be very useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"I want to mail him his password"` - ***NEVER DO THIS***.  This means that you're storing users' passwords in plain text, or at best a reversible encryption.  This is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users.  Passwords should be stored by means of a 1-way hash.  You should ***never*** be able to read a user's password.  If the user forgets his password, provide a form where he can reset it.  But ***do not*** store the password in a readable form and share it back to the user.

Comment: @David.. Thanks.. Its such a useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.MyWebsiteDomainName.com", 25);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@MyWebsiteDomainName.com", "myIDPassword");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

//Setting From , To and CC
mail.From = new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName", "MyWeb Site");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName"));
mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailID@gmail.com"));

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. do i need to import any namespaces?